# I need to access variables across files, what should I do?

Tags: python, class, methods

How can I make `MyClassB` access the `dict k` in `MyClassAC`?

I have two files, the first file is `MyClassB.py`, the content is as follows:

```
class MyClassB:
    print('This is MyClassB!')

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        for _i in cls.codes:
            print(k[_i])  #  What code should I write here to access k defined in MyClassAC?

#If k is relatively large, will it affect performance if it is written in the class attribute?
```

The content of the main file `MyClassAC.py` is as follows:

```
from MyClassB import MyClassB


class MyClassA:
    codes = range(3)
    print('This is MyClassA!')


class MyClassC(MyClassB, MyClassA):
    print('This is MyClassC!')
    pass


k = {}
for i in MyClassC.codes:
    k[i] = MyClassC

MyClassC.run()
```

Comment: I assume this isn't your real code but an example? It's hard to grasp what you're actually trying to do with classes named `MyClassA`, `MyClassC`, etc... and in any case, this looks like misuse of classes where just functions might do.

Comment: The variable itself would need to be in the scope of the class in the form of a global variable, and not a local variable and should be written inside a class if I understand your problem correctly. This could be done by using the ```self``` keyword.

Comment: @AKX Of course, my code is just an example.

Comment: @AidanDonnelly If it exists in the attribute, it needs to exist in the class attribute `cls`, and the `variable k` is relatively large. Does this have an impact on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `k` into the `run()` method:

```py
class MyClassB:
    print('This is MyClassB!')

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, k):
        for _i in cls.codes:
            print(k[_i])
```

and the call can be modified like this:

```py
k = {}
for i in MyClassC.codes:
    k[i] = MyClassC

MyClassC.run(k)
```

Comment: This method can achieve my purpose.